# I'm having trouble sending emails on Django using SMTP. Even after trying various tutorials and checking the documentation, nothing seems to work

Tags: python, django, django-forms, smtp, sendmail

Here are the possible things that may cause my problem.

- using django's live server instead of a domain.

I know in gmail you can't no longer use less secure apps. I enabled two factor authentication and created an app with a unique password. This is what i used for the EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD.

For gmail I used this in my settings.py file

```
DEBUG = True
EMAIL_BACKEND = "django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend"
EMAIL_HOST = "smtp.gmail.com"
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST_USER = "my email address"
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = "my app password"
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = "my email address"
```

Then tried outlook with the same config except for

```
EMAIL_HOST = "smtp-mail.outlook.com"
EMAIL_HOST_USER = "outlook email address"
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = "outlook email address password"
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = "outlook email address"
```

i never had a single success with any of them as I couldn't send out a single mail. Checked my spam folder, inbox folder and all mail folder of the mail recipient.

Comment: I'm not sure why you didn't include any debugging details, including code and error messages.  If you're not getting any errors and the server is accepting the outgoing emails, I'm not sure the problem is something this venue could help you with.

Comment: There is no error coming up from the terminal everything is working on the server just fine, but at the end of the day the emails aren't being sent at all

Comment: Could you try changing the `EMAIL_USE_TLS` and `EMAIL_USE_SSL` parameters. Also I'm assuming you're 100% sure that you send the email in the code and don't just generate the email and never send it?

Comment: yes i am 100% sure, i sent the email in django. I will try what you said though